# Calculate working days between two dates by each month

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint list with start date and end date. I also have 12 calculated columns for each month - Jan to Dec. I want to calculate these columns so that they display working days between start date and end date by each month.
For e.g. for start date : 1/1/2023 | end date : 5/31/2023

I want columns to have data as
Jan : 22
Feb : 21
Mar : 22
Apr : 22
May : 21
June : 0
...
Dec : 0

Can someone help with formula for the same ? i have tried and found business days between start date and end date but not by each month.

Answer (score 0):

```
=(TEXT([DateColumn1],"mm")-(TEXT[DateColumn2],"mm"))
```

That should give you the difference between the months for 2 date fields.

Comment: this did not work.